# Is there a calculator out there that shows the full answer instead of shortening it?

Tags: calculator

I'm looking for a calculator that shows a full answer regardless of it's length.

For example the assignment `2^1000` will output: `1,07150860718626732094842504906e+301`.
Windows calculator shows me that amount because else it won't fit the display.

So the question is:
**Is there a calculator out there that shows the full answer instead of shortening it?**

Comment: What do you expect this hypothetical calculator to display when you enter $\sqrt{ 2 }$ ?

Comment: huh? you mean 4?

Comment: No, I mean 1.41421356..., continuing for ever without repeating.

Comment: Oh, alright. I'm not looking to calculate pi or 10/3. just some sums with very long answers.

Comment: What you want is not usually called a "calculator" but a "computer algebra system".

Comment: Unix has bc for this, what does Windows have?

Comment: There certainly are *calculators* with such functionality.  The HP49/50 series supports arbitrary precision integer arithmetic, and I computed $2^{1000}$ without trouble.  I believe the TI89 series has this as well, but I am not sure.

Comment: wxMaxima and DrRacket are 2 more options, I use both, but they are both more-than-a-calculator.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't mind a web-based solution, wolframalpha.com will do that for you:

```
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2^1000
```

outputs:

> 10715086071862673209484250490600018105614048117055336074437503883703510511249361224931983788156958581275946729175531468251871452856923140435984577574698574803934567774824230985421074605062371141877954182153046474983581941267398767559165543946077062914571196477686542167660429831652624386837205668069376

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly the kind of calculator I need :)

Comment: but even wolfram won't calculate Ack(5,5), so i guess it's a temporary solution :D

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this site](http://alpertron.com/ECM.HTM): it is dedicated to large number factorizations, but you can also make some integer based operations. You can input "2^1000" and try.

Comment: Also a nice one. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can also consider Maple, and Pari-GP.

Comment: http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/

Answer (score 1):

Of course not. Any computer (e.g. calculator) has finite memory, so there will always be numbers that are too long to display fully.

Answer (score 0):

[Wims Function Calculator](http://wims.unice.fr/wims/wims.cgi?session=PKC0C0E5B6.2&lang=en&module=tool%2Fanalysis%2Ffunction.en) also gives 10715086071862673209484250490600018105614048117055336074437503883703510511249361224931983788156958581275946729175531468251871452856923140435984577574698574803934567774824230985421074605062371141877954182153046474983581941267398767559165543946077062914571196477686542167660429831652624386837205668069376.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Python console. Python can work with large numbers, and you can use it as calculator

Comment: Whoever downvoted this guy was probably dumb. This is the easiest and most flexible way!